# How would the "belt trick" analogy of a pion look like?

Tags: particle-physics, quantum-spin, spinors, isospin-symmetry

Since the (charged) pion has a spin of 0, this by itself would suggest that it has spherical symmetry. However, because if it's non-zero iso-spin property it does not have spherical symmetry (is this deduction correct ?).

I was wondering if there is some illustrative way to explain the spin/isospin behaviour of a (charged) pion similar to the "belt trick" illustration of 1/2 spin particles ?

Comment: It has isospin one, so it behaves like a spherical harmonic of l=1 in isospace. No belt trick jazz. Can you refocus your question?

Comment: hmm okay. not sure what exactly "behaves like a spherical harmonic of l=1 in isospace" means in that regard. however, when it comes to rotating the particle, does it mean it is in its original configuration after 1 turn (in any direction) ?

Comment: Yes, nothing funny: behaves like a 3-vector under rotations. Any focus on spinorial antics is misplaced. Isospin space is a notional (Internal symmetry space) mirroring ordinary space and its properties. I would read up on spherical harmonics in your shoes.

Comment: Just to clarify, when you say "behaves like a 3-vector under rotations", does this imply that around a specific axis (the direction of said vector) the pion is fully symmetric and doesn't change at all, while turning around an axis perpendicular to this it will rotate and return to its original configuration after 1 turn ?

Comment: Right. Look at the second line [here](https://i1.wp.com/opticaltweezers.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Fig5_2.png?resize=1024%2C530). This is the pion in isospace.

Comment: Okay cool, thank you. I think I got it now. :) I would take your answer as an answer to my (inappropriate) question, if it weren't a comment ;)